# How to solve this NumberFormatException in spring boot feedback mailsender

Tags: java, nullpointerexception

```
package yash.noteappapi.mail;

import org.springframework.core.env.Environment;

import org.springframework.mail.SimpleMailMessage;
import org.springframework.mail.javamail.JavaMailSenderImpl;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

@Component
public class FeedbackMailSender implements FeedbackSender
{
  private JavaMailSenderImpl mailSender;

  public FeedbackMailSender(Environment environment){
    mailSender = new JavaMailSenderImpl();

    mailSender.setHost(environment.getProperty("spring.mail.host"));
    mailSender.setPort(Integer.parseInt(environment.getProperty("string.mail.port")));
    mailSender.setUsername(environment.getProperty("string.mail.username"));
    mailSender.setPassword(environment.getProperty("spring.mail.password"));
}

  @Override
  public void sendFeedback(String from, String name, String feedback) {
    SimpleMailMessage message = new SimpleMailMessage();
     message.setTo("feedback@noteapp.com");
     message.setSubject("New feedback from " + name);
     message.setText(feedback);
     message.setFrom(from);

    this.mailSender.send(message);
 }
}
```

This is giving the error

> Constructor threw exception; nested exception is
>   java.lang.NullPointerException
>       Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: null

It seems its caused by `Integer.parseInt()` but the port wont be set without parsing it to int since port is an int value, how to solve this

Comment: What does `System.out.println(environment.getProperty("string.mail.port"));` give you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a typo in these two lines:

```
mailSender.setPort(Integer.parseInt(environment.getProperty("string.mail.port")));
mailSender.setUsername(environment.getProperty("string.mail.username"));
```

It should be **spring.mail.port** and **spring.mail.username**

If enviroment properties don't exist they are resolved to null, giving you the NPE in `Integer.parseInt()`

Comment: Haha, well spotted!